# To prove being not isomorphic via connectivity of vertices of certain degrees

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading Richard J. Trudeau's book "[Introduction to Graph Theory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnPwV.png)", in ch 2 there's an example

> Example. The graphs of Figure 35
>   [image: Fig 35] are not isomorphic, even though they share the four
>   properties: in each v = 8 and e = 10; each has four vertices of degree
>   2 and four of degree 3; and they are both in one piece. The structural
>   difference is that the vertices of degree are not related in the same
>   way in the two graphs. **In the first graph the vertices of degree 2
>   come in adjacent pairs**: B is adjacent to H and D is adjacent to F.
>   **But in the second graph they are completely separated from one another by vertices of degree 3**: no vertex of degree is adjacent to
>   any other vertex of degree 2. To see how this prevents the graphs from
>   being isomorphic, we shall systematically try to construct an
>   isomorphism in all possible ways. We begin by noticing that B, being
>   of degree 2, would have to correspond to 1, 3, 6, or 8.
>
> First case: B corresponds to 1.
>
> Then H, being adjacent to B, would have to correspond to 2 or 7. But H
>   must correspond to a vertex having the same degree, so H cannot
>   correspond to either 2 or 7. Therefore no isomorphism is possible if B
>   is made to correspond with 1.
>
> Second case: ...

after discussed all 4 cases, it announces

> We have seen that no isomorphism is possible if B is made to
>   correspond to any of 1, 3, 6, or 8. But under any isomorphism, B would
>   have to correspond to 1, 3, 6, or 8. Therefore no isomorphism is
>   possible, and the graphs of Figure 35 are not isomorphic.

I agree with all the proof process, just, I wonder, is it enough to assert being not isomorphic via connectivity of vertices of certain degrees? Such as, with such differences

> **In the first graph the vertices of degree 2 come in adjacent pairs... But in the second graph they are completely separated from
>   one another by vertices of degree 3**

is it ok to announce the two graphs are not isomorphic? Is there a such general theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is sufficient. For a graph $G$, let $G_d$ be the induced subgraph made by vertices of degree $d$. We have the following

**Lemma**: suppose $f:G \to H$ is an isomorphism of graphs. Then $f| G_d :G_d \to H_d$ is an isomorphism for every $d$.

Indeed, $f$ maps vertices of degree $d$ to vertices of degree $d$: the neighbors of $f(v)$ are exactly $\{f(w)\}$ where $w$ is a neighbor of $w$. So $f|G_d : G_d \to H_d$ is injective and surjective on vertices: injective because it is the restriction of an injective map, surjective because every vertex of degree $d$ must be taken by a vertex of degree $d$. Moreover, for $v,w \in G_d$:
$$(v,w) \in G_d \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \  (v,w) \in G \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \  (f(v),f(w) ) \in H \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \  (f(v),f(w) ) \in H $$
using the property that $f$ is an iso and that $G_d, H_d$ are induced subgraphs.

In your case, set $G$ the graph on the left, $H$ the graph on the right. You have that $G_2$ has two connected components, while $H_2$ has four connected components, so they cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: How are edges in $G$ picked up to form &G_d$?

Comment: Induced subgraph means: take the prescribed vertices, with all the edges between them that comes from the big graph. In symbols $(v,w) \in G_d$ iff $(v,w) \in G$, for $v,w \in G_d$.